# AWS lambda does not access to dynamodb index

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-serverless

Here is my SAM Template section for the function needing to query the index.

```
userSignIn:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./
      Handler: src/handlers/users/userSignIn.userSignInHandler
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 60
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
          TableName: go-time
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DYNAMODB_TABLE: go-time
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /users/login
            Method: POST
```

When I run the function locally it works. Im assuming it is because the IAM role is Admin, but when I run it on API Gateway I recieve and error saying the function does not have access to /go-time/index/username-index

Comment: To provide enough context to answer your question, please also post the code you use to query DynamoDB and the exact error message.

Comment: [DynamoDBCrudPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-template-list.html#dynamo-db-crud-policy) covers indices. Thus the question is, what action is denied?